# Print list of all Eclipse quick fix suggestions for the active project

Tags: java, compiler-construction, eclipse-plugin

I want to write a piece of Java code to call Eclipse quick fix and print all its suggestions in the console.

As an example, if I have a reference to an undefined variable, then the compiler error will be  **cannot be resolved to a variable**. In this case, Eclipse suggestes some fixes such as **Create Local Variable**, **Create Field**, or **Create Parameter**. In my project I want to print this three suggestions as output.

I saw this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609667/is-it-possible-to-call-quickfix-solutionseclipse-for-specificerror-s), but not useful.

Please let me know what is the best way to do this task.

Comment: The answer you reference is correct, this is quite a complex requirement that is too large for an SO answer. Do you have any experience of writing Eclipse plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to extend **org.eclipse.jdt.ui.quickFixProcessors** plug-in, and also extends **IJavaCompletionProposal** interface.

This [web page](http://jaxenter.de/artikel/Eclipse-JDT-um-eigene-Quickfixes-erweitern) describes all details that you need. It is in Germany, but I am sure you can use Google translator to have it is English. Hope, it helps.

Comment: Thanks. The solution in the web page helps me to know better how to extend the necessary plugin, and do what I needed.